# powershell copy all folders and files in folder

Tags: powershell, copy

Probably very easy for you guys.

I want to copy all the folders and files from this path c:\default\
to this destination c:\environment\customfolder\
in the folder customerfolder are other folders with different names.
It should only copy the files and folders to the destination Where the customfolder contains the name DEMO_test

What is the best and easiest way to do that?
should I use for-each?

## thanks for your help.

Sorry I should be more clear. ;-)

I have a folder c:\default

All the files and sub-folders in that folder c:\default

should be copied to these folders

c:\environment\customfolder\demo_test

c:\environment\customfolder\demo_test01

c:\environment\customfolder\demo_test02

c:\environment\customfolder\demo_test03

I know it should be possible to copy all files and sub-folders from this path (source)c:\default\

to this path (destination)c:\environment\customfolder\

And only copy it to the folders if they have the name (like) demo_test*

Is that question better?

thanks.

Comment: Your requirement is a bit unclear... perhaps you can provide some example source and destination filepaths?

Answer (score 4):

Get a list of files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\default\" -Recurse
```

The `-Recurse` parameter searches subfolders.

Now filter the list to show only files that fit a certain pattern

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\default\" -Recurse |
    Where-Object Name -like "*test*"
```

Note that the pipe `|` is effectively chaining these commands together.

Now copy the filtered list of items to a destination folder:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\default\" -Recurse |
    Where-Object Name -like "*test*" | 
    Copy-Item -Destination "C:\destination\"
```

Comment: Thanks gvee for your fast reply.
The only thing is that it should only copy to the destination folders that contain for example the name test.
I have tried that with the where-object name but that doesn't seem to wrok is that correct?

Comment: so the filter on the  name should be on the destination path

Comment: @michieln sorry - don't follow. Really need more information in your original question. Examples of source and destination folders/files would be most illustrative.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you corectly you have flat structure of catalogs:
SOURCE:
C\Catalog[lookupCatalogs]\files
DEST:
c:\Catalog\SomeCatlogs[lookupCatalogs]\files

if yes,

this function should be ok:

```
function copy-TestdemoFolders
{
    param ($source,
    $destination,
    $filter,
    $recursive = $false)


$folders = Get-ChildItem  $source -filter $filter -Directory

$folders | % {

    $copyPath = Join-Path $destination $_.name

    if (!(Test-Path $copyPath))
    {
        New-Item $copyPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
        "Created New Folder: $($_.name)"
    }

    $scriptBlock = { Get-ChildItem $_.Fullname }

    if ($recursive -eq $true)
    {
        $scriptBlock = { Get-ChildItem $_.Fullname -Recurse }
    }

    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock | %{

        Copy-Item $_.Fullname $copyPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        if (!($?)) { $error[0].Exception.Message }

    }
  }
}


copy-TestdemoFolders -source 'C:\Source' -filter "*demo_test*" -destination D:\TEST
```

You can recursively copy files from subfolders to [lookupCatalog] with switch `copy-TestdemoFolders -source 'C:\Source' -filter "*demo_test*" -destination D:\TEST -recursive:$true`

Comment: Sorry I should be more clear. ;-)

I have a folder c:\default

Comment: Sorry I should be more clear. ;-)

I have a folder c:\default
All the files and sub-folders in that folder c:\default 
should be copied to these folders c:\environment\customfolder\demo_test
c:\environment\customfolder\demo_test01
c:\environment\customfolder\demo_test02
c:\environment\customfolder\demo_test03

I know it should be possible to copy all files and sub-folders from this path (source)c:\default\ 
to this path (destination)c:\environment\customfolder\
And only copy it to the folders if they have the name (like) demo_test*

Is that question better? 
thanks.